# TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;authorization&#39; of undefined using express-jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt

I am trying to add routes authentication for that I am using `express-jwt` I added this middleware to protect post creation routes. But while testing I get the error in postman.

> error

`TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;authorization&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.getTokenFromHeaders [as getToken]`

These are my code for express jwt

> auth.js

```
import  jwt from 'express-jwt';
const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
    const { headers: { authorization } } = req;
    console.log(authorization);     <----- in this log i am getting token
    if(authorization && authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Token') {
        return authorization.split(' ')[1];

    }
    return null;
};

const auth = {
    required: jwt({
        secret: 'secret',
        userProperty: 'payload',
        getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
    }),
    optional: jwt({
        secret: 'secret',
        userProperty: 'payload',
        getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
        credentialsRequired: false,
    }),
};

module.exports = auth;
```

> routes.js

`routes.post('/post', auth.required, postController.post);`

Comment: I get This in my console.log()  `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkaXR5YWttciIsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRpdHlha21yOTk2NjhAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxN
TY0MDE5MTU4fQ.qPGA5gg1_38aNaKLJqnjiIjmMxfuzwWNoykhM7xkgn0
`

Comment: I changed my question I put `req.body` by mistake, I fixed them with `req` Now i get the token but still not authorized `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```js
const { headers: { authorization } } = req.body;
```

Because `headers` prop is on `req` object, not on `req.body`, so it should be like this instead:

```js
const { headers: { authorization } } = req;
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed them  still I get this error `UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
`

Comment: That's a different error, most likely due to `getTokenFromHeaders` returned `null` for your request

Comment: Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `=== 'Token'` instead of `=== 'Bearer'`? You showed yourself that yout header includes `Bearer` word, not `Token`. So your function returns `null`

Comment: Yeah, I did not see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `const authorization = req.headers.authorization` it should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me out:

```
 const { headers: { authorization } } = req;
 const token = authorization && authorization.split(" ")[1];
```